# SQL Query with recursive hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchy with this kind of structure :

```
  * organization
    * organization
    * organization
      * site
        * voice_acount
        * voice_acount
        * voice_acount
      * site
        * voice_acount
  * organization
    * organization
      * site
```

- A site always have an organization_id
- A voice_account always have a site_id
- An organization may have a parent_organization_id

I need to count all voice accounts from a given organization uuid with recursivity inside the hierarchy.

For exemple if i give the root organization uuid, i need to count all the voice_account under no matter where they are in the hierarchy.

Actually i have this request which is functionnal :

```sql
select count(*) from voice_account va
inner join site s on va.site_id = s.id 
where s.organization_id in (

  with recursive hierarchy as (
    select id from organization
    where id = '53aa1663-c759-4807-a8d5-xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    
    union all 
    
    select o.id from organization o, hierarchy
    where o.parent_organization_id = hierarchy.id
  )
  select id
  from hierarchy

)
and va.deleted_at is null
```

I'm pretty shure we can optimize its performances but i don't know how.
Any idea ?

PS : the actual execution time is around 500/600ms

Comment: We don't know either. You didn't show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output.

Comment: I would compute the hierarchy table once and use it as the driving table in a join, instead of using an `IN` operator -- that could be quite expensive.

Comment: Can a site be linked to an organisation that is not at the bottom of an organisation hierarchy ? Is the depth of the organisation hierarchy only what you’ve shown or could it be deeper? If the hierarchy is as simple as you’ve shown (in terms of depth) then I probably wouldn’t bother with recursion and would just explicitly self-join the table

Answer (score 0):

This should simplify the code to make it more readable:

```
with recursive hierarchy as (
  select id
  from organization
  where id = '53aa1663-c759-4807-a8d5-xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  
  union all 
  select o.id
  from organization o
    inner join hierarchy h on o.parent_organization_id = h.id
)

select count(*)
from voice_account va
  inner join site s on va.site_id = s.id 
  inner join hierarchy h on h.id = s.organization_id
where va.deleted_at is null
```

Using a temporary table to store the hierarchy output may make things faster.  I don't have experience with Postgresql, but in SQL Server it would look something like this:

```
with recursive hierarchy as (
  select id
  from organization
  where id = '53aa1663-c759-4807-a8d5-xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  
  union all 
  select o.id
  from organization o
    inner join hierarchy h on o.parent_organization_id = h.id
)

select *
into #hTemp
from hierarchy

select count(*)
from voice_account va
  inner join site s on va.site_id = s.id 
  inner join #hTemp h on h.id = s.organization_id
where va.deleted_at is null
```